# Lombok @Builder does not create immutable objects?

Tags: java, builder, lombok

In many sites, I saw lombok @Builder can be used to create immutable objects here(https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-singular) and also many sites say Builder pattern is mainly used to create immutable objects.

```
TimeIntervalData td = TimeIntervalData.builder().endTime("12:00").startTime("10:00").build();
td.setEndTime("14:00");
System.out.println(td.getEndTime());
```

I am not sure how I can use setters on objects built using builders. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes lombok builder will not create immutable instances util user define the parameters in class as `final`, As per the docs from [lombok.builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) `@Builder` lets you automatically produce the code required to have your class be instantiable with code such as:

```
Person.builder().name("Adam Savage").city("San Francisco").job("Mythbusters").job("Unchained Reaction").build();
```

As per the docs it just creates inner static class with the same properties in the same way that mentioned in outer class

> A method annotated with @Builder (from now on called the target) causes the following 7 things to be generated:

- An inner static class named FooBuilder, with the same type arguments as the static method (called the builder).
- In the builder: One private non-static non-final field for each parameter of the target.
- In the builder: A package private no-args empty constructor.
- **In the builder: A 'setter'-like method for each parameter of the target: It has the same type as that parameter and the same name. It returns the builder itself, so that the setter calls can be chained**
- In the builder: A build() method which calls the method, passing in each field. It returns the same type that the target returns
- In the builder: A sensible toString() implementation.
- In the class containing the target: A builder() method, which creates a new instance of the builder.

But using [@Singular](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) with `@Builder` annotation for collection properties makes them singleton

> By annotating one of the parameters (if annotating a method or constructor with @Builder) or fields (if annotating a class with @Builder) with the @Singular annotation, lombok will treat that builder node as a collection, and it generates 2 'adder' methods instead of a 'setter' method. One which adds a single element to the collection, and one which adds all elements of another collection to the collection. No setter to just set the collection (replacing whatever was already added) will be generated.
>
> @Singular can only be applied to collection types known to lombok.

Comment: "That's correct lombok builder will not create immutable instances util user define the parameters in class as final" this line clears it, I feel I had a misconception that builder pattern is mostly used to create immutable objects.

Comment: @mayukh45 That's not a misconception. Immutable objects often need a builder (if you want to avoid too-any-args constructors), while mutable don't (you can even get fluent syntax with Lombok setters). However, `lombok.Builder` doesn't care whether it's really needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

> is mainly used to create immutable objects

This statement is not correct. The main purpose is to reduce boiler plate code. Creation of object using builder is compacter, it is easier to write and is easier to read.

When you have 1-2 attributes, builder can be disadvantage and can make the code less readable compared to passing parameters via constructor.

So when to use or not to use builder is a matter of taste.

To setters: If you need setters, you can generate them by *@Data* annotation.

Comment: Both statements concerning "main" usage (immutable objects / reduce boilerplate code) are equally groundless. Unless there's a citation and a definition of "mainly used" or "main purpose"

Comment: @fdreger: Look at their web site (https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) *No-hassle fancy-pants APIs for object creation!* Or here (https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder) *@Builder is a useful mechanism for using the Builder pattern without writing boilerplate code*. Furthermore just think of a JPA entity that has 30 attributes. If the variable name consists of 10-15 characters, be using builder you avoid 30 x (13-18) = 390 - 549 characters on a single place. Tell us what is this if not boiler plate.